# Internet Explorer missing from Windows Features

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, skype

I've disabled Internet Explorer in the list of "Windows Features" on Windows 10, but then days later I realized that the desktop version of Skype seems to require it to be enabled in order to let me login to my account (it says, "Sorry, we couldn't connect to Skype").

I've ruled out firewall problems and other possible causes for that, updated Windows, and reinstalled Skype, so I'm certain I need to reenable Internet Explorer. However, IE is now missing from "Windows Features" and I can't find a way to add it back. See the screenshot below.

I've already run commands such as  **sfc /scannow** and **DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth**, but they gave no error messages.

Is there anything else I may try instead of "resetting" Windows 10 and losing all my customizations and risk breaking other programs in vain?

[image: Windows Features]

Comment: Try this command `Dism /Online /Get-Packages` to find all the features available.

Comment: That shows mostly language-related features. No mention of IE.

Comment: But your command made me open the "Manage optional features" in the new Settings "app" (where I had seen the language stuff before), and the "Add a feature" listed Internet Explorer! I'm going to restart my laptop now to see if it worked.

Comment: Try this command `Dism /Online /Get-Features`. Mistakenly, the first command was for packages.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to get Internet Explorer back going to the Settings "app" - Apps - Apps & features - Manage optional features - Add a feature - Internet Explorer 11, and then restarting my computer.

Skype still won't work, though. :(

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/756229/user756229) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/756236/user1user2user3). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 3):

Spent hours trying to get this to work last night and finally was able to. I had the same issue where iexplore.exe was missing in both Program Files and Program Files x86, and also didn't have an option for it in the "turn windows features on or off" section or in the new Settings panel for an available feature. Here are the steps that got it to work for me:

1. First, get your hands on a recent Windows 10 ISO here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
2. Use the media creation tool and simply have it spit out an ISO image somewhere on your hard drive.
3. Next, make sure to update Windows 10 to the latest version by going into Settings > Update & Security > Check for updates.
4. After Windows is fully updated, open up powershell as an administrator.
5. Next, you'll want to find the ISO file that you put on your hard drive and mount it so that you can browse the files
6. Browse the mounted ISO. You'll want to open up sources > sxs and there should be about 4 or more files in there, one of them named "microsoft-windows-interenetexplorer-optional-package.cab"
7. In powershell, put in the following (replace my E:\sources.... with the actual location of the cab file on your system): dism /online /add-package /packagepath:E:\sources\sxs\microsoft-windows-internetexplorer-optional-package.cab
8. If your ISO is up-to-date and your Windows 10 OS is up-to-date, it should install and ask you to restart
9. After restart, you should be able to go to Settings > Apps > Manage Optional Features > Add a Feature > Internet Explorer 11
   OR
   Go to Control Panel by searching for it after hitting the start button, then go to Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off and then check the box for Internet Explorer 11 and restart

Answer (score 0):

in Powershell

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 –Online
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend upgrading the computer to 21H1 first, then downloading the 21h1 iso to the root C drive.  Once you mount the iso to the root of C drive it will likely become D or E drive. In my case it has been D both times. You can do this with other versions of windows as well, but will need to adjust the commands accordingly.

Next, run these 2 commands in Powershell as administrator.

dism /online /add-package /packagepath:"D:\sources\sxs\microsoft-windows-internetexplorer-optional-package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~.cab”

Reboot No

Hit enter then run this command next:

dism /online /add-package /packagepath:"D:\sources\sxs\Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-Optional-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~.cab”

Reboot yes

IE should then be in the start menu.

If it's still missing you can try the following:

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 –Online

or

dism /online /enable-feature:"Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64"
Verify Internet Explorer shows up in the start menu.